# After undocking my laptop, Aero Glass stopped working, and ZoomIt now has two mouse pointers

Tags: windows-7, aero, hp-elitebook

I undocked my laptop earlier, and when I got to the meeting and lifted the cover on the laptop, I noticed that the Glass Aero theme had stopped working, in the sense that window borders were no longer transparent.

Additionally, when I now use ZoomIt, I have two mouse pointers, one big and one small, and ZoomIt is not as smooth as it was before.

Could some kind of graphics acceleration have taken a hit when I undocked, and there's something I need to enable to get it working again?

I used ZoomIt just this morning, before the meeting, so I know it worked earlier today, I have not installed or uninstalled anything that provoked this, no Windows update, no configuration changes, except that I undocked my machine and took it to a meeting.

Has anyone experienced this and know how to solve it?

I have googled for how to enable Aero Glass, and verified that the registry settings are indeed as they should be, and I've restarted the theme manager, to no avail. I have also changed theme back and forth and restarted between each change, no change.

What else?

As a side-note, a colleague of mine with a different laptop model has had the same problem since he got his machine but we chalked it up to having different graphics drivers or something similar. Since he's not using ZoomIt as much, he just accepted that perhaps it wouldn't work on his machine, but now I'm not so sure.

The machine is a HP EliteBook 8530p, running Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit, if that matters, but as I said, it all worked nicely earlier today, but changed when I undocked.

**Edit**: I also just noticed that when docked, I have two displays, two 1280x1024 displays, and when I drag a window around, ie. moving it, and start moving it out the left of my leftmost display, I can keep dragging it as though there's an extra display in that direction. If I drag a window off the rightmost display, I get the "scale to one half a display on the right side" overlay to indicate that I can do that, but on the leftmost display, there seems to be an additional third display over there. Not sure this is relevant though, and I can't say for sure whether this has been like that before, I've certainly not noticed it.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it was definitely my own fault, but I don't know why it decided to kick in today when I undocked my machine.

I had [Air Display](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/air-display/id368158927?mt=8) for iPad installed, a mirroring driver, that suddenly decided to give up its life.

After running the troubleshooting wizard for Aero Glass problems multiple times (the problem wasn't listed the first time around), it showed that I had a mirroring display driver that didn't support the Glass functionality.

I knew that it didn't, because any time I hooked my iPad up to the machine for mirrored display during presentations, it turned off Glass for the duration of the connection, however today it decided to just enable itself and then die on me.

Uninstalled that program, and restarted, and everything was back in order.